# generating dynamic addthis toolboxes that point at other urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, addthis

so, I have a list of blog posts that have infinite scroll (the next page renders dynamically when you scroll to the bottom with no page refresh). I want to have the addthis stats visible from the list. I set something like:

```
<?php foreach($results as $r): ?>
<!-- HTML post markup --><div class="post">BLAH!</div>

    <div class="post-detail-footer clearfix">
        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
        <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style " addthis:url="<?php echo $link ?>" addthis_title="<?php echo $r['title']; ?>">
        <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
        <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
        </div>
        <!-- AddThis Button END -->
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-513a6f8b612e023f&async=1"></script>
<script>    addthis.init();</script>
```

after you scroll to the bottom the next page renders the new content dynamically using exactly the same formatting as above with different content except the ".addthis_toolbox" divs have an additional class: 'addthis-needed'. THEN, I use javascript to try to render those addthis bars.

```
    addthis.toolbox('.addthis-needed');
    $('.addthis-needed').removeClass('addthis-needed');
```

This is where I'm stuck. of the toolboxes that render some of them work as they should, but some of them give me this: (see screenshot)[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found that you can add the url directly to the facebook/twitter buttons. I followed these directions and it worked for me: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/125634-setting-the-url-to-share